# I have a 32 char long string. The chars are only 0 and 1, like 00010010101.... I simply need the int value that is represented by that in C#

Tags: c#, string, binary, integer

The title says everything basically. I am sure that there is same basic function that I don't know I don't normally use C#.

Not enterly sure what this does: '''Convert.ToInt32(binaryValue, 2);''' either way it does not work.

Comment: _"it does not work"_ means nothing here. Always explain _how_ it doesn't work. That could encompass: throws an exception, does not behave as expected, does not yield expected results, crashes the app, ...

Comment: _"Not enterly sure what this does"_ - you can always consult [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-7.0#system-convert-toint32(system-string-system-int32)).

Answer (score 2):

This should work with you without problems as far as the string width is limited to 32 characters.

```
   string binarystring = "00110101010111010111010110010011";

   int intvalue = Convert.ToInt32(binarystring, 2);

   Console.WriteLine(intvalue);
```